# How to reuqst permissions again when they were rejected at first?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have developed a Web application that authenticates using Facebook.

I have requested user_location permissions so the user sees a page to allow or reject the permissions, however, if the user rejected the permission at the current moment, is it possible to grant permissions later?

Furthermore, when the permissions page appeared, I click the link that says "in other moment", so I thought the confirmation will appear again when user tries to login in other time.

For instance, I, as the developer, used the link "in other moment" to take into account that situation. But I don't know how to grant permissions now, to be able to test the other part.

How can I do this?

EDIT:

This is how I am calling API:

```
<?php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                             'app_id' => $api_key,
                             'app_secret' => $api_secret,
                             'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
                             'persistent_data_handler' => 'session',
                             ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email', 'user_location']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_login_url, $permissions);
?>
<input type="button" value="Ingresar con facebook" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginUrl ?>'; return false;" title="Conéctese a su cuenta Facebook; return false;">
```

Comment: You have to add the parameter `auth_type` with value `rerequest` to your login dialog call. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.10#params

Comment: Where do I need to add that parameter? I have edited the question to show how I am instantiating API.

Comment: Should have mentioned that you're using the PHP SDK, the redirect login helper class has a dedicated method for this purpose, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper#get-re-request-url

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly!

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the user rejected the permission at the current moment, is it possible to grant permissions later?

You have to add the parameter `auth_type` with value `rerequest` to your login dialog call.

The PHP SDK's redirect login helper class has a dedicated method for this purpose, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper#get-re-request-url